# Getting outputs from a "for" loop in r into a matrix or data frame

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, matrix

I am trying to perform the following loop:

1. Compare each of the n rows of my matrix X with a X.prototype matrix.
2. Find the closest row of X.prototype to each row of X.
3. if the two rows have the same label (y and y.prototype), then bring the values close; otherwise, put them further.

My code:

```
for (i in (1:n)){ 
  
  closest.row <- which.min(colSums((t(X.prototype) - X[i,])^2))
  
  X.new.x1 <- ifelse(y.prototype[closest.row] == y[i],
                     X.prototype[closest.row,1]+(eta*(X[i,1]-X.prototype[closest.row,1])),
                     X.prototype[closest.row,1]-(eta*(X[i,1]-X.prototype[closest.row,1])))
  X.new.x2<- ifelse(y.prototype[closest.row] == y[i],
                    X.prototype[closest.row,2]+(eta*(X[i,2]-X.prototype[closest.row,2])),
                    X.prototype[closest.row,2]-(eta*(X[i,2]-X.prototype[closest.row,2])))
  X.new <- matrix(c(X.new.x1,X.new.x2),ncol=2) 

  plot(X.new.x2~X.new.x1)

 print(X.new)
  
}


----------


set.seed(123)                        # Set seed for reproducibility
n <- 100
X <- cbind(x1 = runif(n, -1.5, 1.5),
           x2 = runif(n, -1.5, 1.5)) # Generate random points
y <- as.integer(rowSums(X^2)<1)      # Determine whether inside the circle#
idx <- sample(100, 10)               # Mess up 10 class labels ...
y[idx] <- 1-y[idx]                   # ... by flipping the label

is <- c(sample(which(y==0),K), sample(which(y==1),K))
X.prototype <- X[is,]
y.prototype <- y[is]                 # Will be K times 0, followed by K times 1

K <- 10
eta <- 0.25
H <- 25
```

The problem is that the outcomes come out as single vectors, and I am unable to bring them together in a `X.new` matrix, to use for new predictions and to plot it.

[this is a link to how my output looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWY9V.png)

[This is how I'd like them to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVhER.png)

Thank you
S

Comment: what is the `class` of  `X.new`?

Answer (score 0):

Try these changes:

```
#Initial dataframe
X.df <- data.frame()
#Loop
for (i in (1:n)){ 
  
  closest.row <- which.min(colSums((t(X.prototype) - X[i,])^2))
  
  X.new.x1 <- ifelse(y.prototype[closest.row] == y[i],
                     X.prototype[closest.row,1]+(eta*(X[i,1]-X.prototype[closest.row,1])),
                     X.prototype[closest.row,1]-(eta*(X[i,1]-X.prototype[closest.row,1])))
  X.new.x2<- ifelse(y.prototype[closest.row] == y[i],
                    X.prototype[closest.row,2]+(eta*(X[i,2]-X.prototype[closest.row,2])),
                    X.prototype[closest.row,2]-(eta*(X[i,2]-X.prototype[closest.row,2])))
  X.new <- matrix(c(X.new.x1,X.new.x2),ncol=2) 

  #Bind
  X.df <- rbind(X.df,X.new)
    
  plot(X.new.x2~X.new.x1)
  
}
print(X.df)
```

Output:

```
head(X.df)
          V1         V2
1 -0.5464952  0.2673293
2  0.8649154 -0.5015294
3 -0.4554457  0.1837973
4  0.8687970  1.0649177
5  0.7507938 -0.6140885
6 -1.3711987  1.3144680
```

You would need an empty dataframe and `rbind` to obtain a squared structure.

Comment: Hi @Duck ,
Thanks for your answer.
However, even with those changes, I get 100 matrices for each row:

example:

           [,1]      [,2]
[1,] -0.4458489 -0.796795
           [,1]      [,2]
[1,] -0.1011919 0.5764171

Comment: EDIT:
You are right! this works! however it plots only the last point of the matrix for some reason.